# Tags `hashmap` and `dictionary` seems to be the same

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Tags [hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashmap) and [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) seems to be the same.

Please make one alias to the other.

Comment: Do you have any statistics or details showing how each tag has been used?   There may be some non-abstract cases where they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. HashMap is a specific implementation that exist in Java, where Dictionary seems to be a more generic tag.

Comment: Taking "dictionary" as the generic CS data structure, there are other ways to implement it than with a hash table. These are not synonymous at all.

Comment: Don't just program in [php] please.

Comment: what do you think we should do with [tag:associative-array] which is the more scientific and correct generalized term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not the same. A hashmap and a dictionary are not interchangeable, as pointed out by several people in the comments already.

Even if you say that "dictionary" is a generic type of data structure, a hash-map is only one of its possible implementations. Furthermore, the are languages/frameworks that provide specific HashMap and Dictionary types, and questions about these would merit the use of these tags.

A synonym is not appropriate here. If you see an individual question that misuses the tags, feel free to retag it as needed.